# Why is this suggested edit of a question title displaying peculiarly?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, title

I'm looking at a [suggested edit](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/21003) to the title of [How can I get exposure to mandarin usage and pronounciation?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17132/how-can-i-get-exposure-to-mandarin-usage-and-pronounciation) at Chinese.SE:

[image: How can I get exposure to mandarin usage and pronounciation?How can I get exposure to Mandarin usage and pronunciation?]

I almost rejected it, thinking it would change the title to the following:

> How can I get exposure to usage and ?How can I get exposure to Mandarin usage and pronunciation?

Realistically the edit should be indicated by something more natural, like:

> How can I get exposure to <s>mandarin</s> Mandarin usage and <s>pronounciation?</s> pronunciation?

I don't know if this is just limited to this single question.

**Question**: Why is this suggested edit of a question title displaying peculiarly?

I'm on Mozilla Firefox for Linux Mint <s>78.0.2 (64-bit)</s> now updated to 79.0 (64-bit).  I turned off my StackApps scripts via Tampermonkey (in particular [Review Stalker Reloaded](https://stackapps.com/questions/6869/review-stalker-reloaded-a-cross-site-dashboard-for-reviews)), but it didn't change anything.  I'm using the [XX-net](https://github.com/XX-net/XX-Net) proxy to get around the great firewall in China; it won't load otherwise.

---

A very similar [already approved edit](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20825) (also by Glorfindel) looks fine:

> [image]

Comment: Interesting. No idea off-hand, but I see the diff the way you're suggesting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtr3w.png

Comment: Also no repro in Firefox Nightly 81.0a1. There are no buttons for “Markdown view” and “Rendered view” or something, are there?

Comment: *sigh* did I break things again?

Comment: That suggestion renders correctly for me. FF 78.0.2 x64 Win10.

Comment: Would it show-up like on your screen, I'd have my doubts about the edit too.

Comment: @user289905 There should be, [this is how Suggested Edits reviews look for me on Code Review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D89sK.png). At least a 'Rendered output' and 'Markdown' option should be available, but perhaps those aren't included in title-only edits or went missing for another reason...

Comment: _“looks fine”_ — I’ve never seen the title being split into two columns, and it doesn’t show like this for me. Are you sure that’s not an extension or user-script?

Comment: I have some Tampermonkey scripts, but nothing changes even if I switch Tampermonkey off entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, sorry everyone.  It is a script after all: [The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup).  I had it installed as an add-on (so it was unaffected by turning Tampermonkey off), and I didn't even realize it was there.

Turning it off makes everything look appropriate:

> [image]

Comment: Mystery solved :)